# AWS iOS v2 Cognito vs STS authentication

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Recently i decide to understand what approach is more suitable for the mobile clients to interact with server side of the S3. I am using Cognito approach to upload images and video to the server and it works brilliant.

Nevertheless i am interested in STS and if is fully supported in iOS SDK v2 and pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

STS is fully supported by the iOS V2 SDK.  Cognito offers a few advantages over WIF with STS.

1. Unauthenticated users
2. The ability to link users' Amazon, Google and Facebook logins to the same identity.
3. The ability to sync small amounts data for a fee.

Comment: OK, but [is it free to use Amazon Cognito to authenticate users?](http://serverfault.com/questions/698650/is-it-free-to-use-amazon-cognito-to-authenticate-users)

Comment: Yes it is free to authenticate users.